# Windows7 cheapest price, OEM versions vs. product-key only?

Tags: windows-7, oem, product-key

I'm looking for the cheapest solution to get a Windows 7 to my netcafe.
Personally I use Gnu/Linux but apparently most of people don't.
I'm thinking of ordering [windows product keys](http://www.windows-product.com) only, to cut the cost from this [website](http://www.windows-product.com).

But I'm afraid that this is illegal site i.e. it sells key-gen made product keys.
I thought about getting OEM editions.

Microsoft does not reveal any info about the price of open volume licensing. (I need 8 copies only for now)

Comment: Read the [FAQs](http://superuser.com/faq) SuperUser is **not** for shopping recommendations.

Comment: Looks like a very bad made piracy side. They didn't even remove "Lorem Ipsum" from the bottom of their page and you do not find anything but spam for their domain.

Comment: @wizlog et al, is there a StackExchange site where technology shopping questions are appropriate? Sadly, Windows OS pricing is a difficult problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tip 1: Shitty grammar on some of their FAQ pages. Red flag to me

Tip 2: If you're worried about something being legit, go to the source of the product, or at least a good retailer

Tip 3: Lack of a Contact Us page

Comment: +1 -- getting a 404 on a 'contact us' page is never a good sign